# Chrome Vox Shift Alt Left arrow reads all following elements on page

Tags: screen-readers, wcag

Chrome Vox Shift Alt Left arrow reads all following elements on page on following structure. Now keeps focus on first input, I am trying to move from Input to label, and focus goes on asterisk span and label both. And it reads next input (email input box)and span also. Is there any fix for this?

```
<span>* </span>
<label for="name">Name:</label> 
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<br/>
<span>* </span>
<label for="email">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
```

Comment: Is this ChromeVox on ChromeOS or just within the browser on Windows/Mac?

Comment: This is Chrome Browser on windows machine. I found another sample site where you can find same issue.. (here structure is different with which is mentioned in question ) https://www.deque.com/padam/demo/demo-accessible-client-side-form-validation-with-html5-wai-aria.html. Enable Chromevox and use Vox key (Shift+Alt in my case) plus Right arrow from Last Name field to First Name, when focus reach at FirstName label, it starts reading all elements.

Comment: Ah. Cannot offer much help as I do not use ChromeVox. It is not a true screen reader so it does not always behave as one might expect. That being said, most screen browsers will not let you put focus on a `<label>` as its job is to shift focus to the associated field. I also may be misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very confusing to answer. But this is how I understood it... You don't want the chromevox screen reader to announce the asterisk.

So what you can do is add this to the span.

```
<span aria-hidden="true">* </span>
```

Now I'm assuming you are using an asterisk to signify something is required... so you should add this to the input

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
```

You need to add required to the input.

Now you can also control the flow of how the screen reader reads elements using tab index. But typically people don't use tab-index of a positive integer so it would need to be tab-index="0"

Hope This helps!